# Limit of the average of the laplacian of a test function and a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous function, and $B(x,r)$ the ball of center $x$ and radius $r>0$ in $ \mathbb{R}^{m} $ with $m\geq1$. We know that there exists a test function $\phi_{r}(t)$ that is between 0 and 1, its support is in $B(x,r)$ and is equal to 1 on the closure of $B(x,r/2)$. Let $\theta$ be a smooth function whose Laplacian is identically 1 everywhere. What is
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{\lambda r^{m}}\int_{B(x,r)}f(t)\Delta(\phi_{r}(t)\theta(t))dt?$$ (  $\lambda$ is the volume of the unit ball in $ \mathbb{R}^{m} $ and $\Delta$ is the laplacian)